# Exibir seleção de dia com php e pdo

Tags: php, mysql

Nessa pagina estou fazendo aniversariantes do mês, e eu consegui exibir todos os aniversariantes que tem no mes atual, porém não estou conseguindo exibir o dia sendo que eu também selecionei no banco de dados...

```html
                   <?php
                            require 'cfg/db.php';

                             $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
                             $sql = 'SELECT id, nome, membro, foto, data_nascimento, DAY(data_nascimento) FROM membros WHERE DAY(data_nascimento) AND MONTH(data_nascimento)';
                             $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
                             $stm->execute();
                             $aniversariantes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                             print_r($aniversariantes);
                      ?>

                      <?php 
            
            foreach($aniversariantes as $aniversariante):

                      ?>

                      <tr class="table-row">
                            <td class="table-img">
                              <img src='fotos/<?=$aniversariante->foto?>' height='40' width='40'>
                            </td>
                            <td class="table-text">
                              <h6><?=$aniversariante->nome?></h6>
                                <p><?=$aniversariante->membro?></p>
                            </td>

                            <td class="march">
                               Dia: 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
            <?php 

            endforeach;
            
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude seu `select` para:

```
SELECT id, nome, membro, foto, data_nascimento, DAY(data_nascimento) AS dia_nascimento FROM membros WHERE DAY(data_nascimento) AND MONTH(data_nascimento)
```

e na hora de imprimir você faz assim:

```
<td class="march">
    Dia: <? echo $aniversariante->dia_nascimento; ?>
</td>
```

O `AS` funciona como um apelido, então a coluna de nome `DAY(data_nascimento)` foi apelidada como `dia_nascimento`.

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado ! você poderia me ajudar em mais uma coisa?

Comment: qual a dúvida? Se for muito extensa o ideal é criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: é que ela esta em yyyy/mm/dd queria colocar ela no formato do brasil

Comment: Para formatar a data você utiliza a função `DATE_FORMAT`, então ficaria assim `DATE_FORMAT(DATE(data_nascimento), "%d/%m/%Y") AS dia_nascimento` no lugar de `DAY(data_nascimento) AS dia_nascimento`.

Comment: consegui, muito obrigado !